# tableView.setContentOffset not working on UITableView embedded in UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, model-view-controller

I had this code in a UITableViewController and it worked perfectly.

```
func setupSearchBar() {
    let searchBar: UISearchBar = searchController.searchBar
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar

    let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchBar.frame.size.height)
    tableView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true    
}
```

Now I'm refactoring my code to fit more of an MVC style architecture. What I did is create a UITableView in the View class:

```
class View: UIView {
   lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
      let table = UITableView()
      table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      return table
   }()

    func configureView() {

       // tableView
       addSubview(tableView)
       tableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
       tableView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
       tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
       tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

and then use the View class in my ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var newView: View! { return self.view as! View }

    override func loadView() {
        view = View(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        newView.configureView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupSearchBar()    
    }

    func setupSearchBar() {
        let searchBar: UISearchBar = searchController.searchBar
        newView.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar

        let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchBar.frame.size.height)
        newView.tableView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)   
    }
```

The tableView shows up no problem and everything else is fine. The only thing that's not working is the setContentOffset is being called, but it's not offsetting the content. I want the searchbar to be hidden by default when the user first opens this viewController (similar to iMessage), but after I moved the code from a UITableViewController to separate files (UIView + UIViewController) like in this example, the searchbar always shows by default.

I'm not sure why it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Beautifully posed question. Absolutely clear, precisely relevant information provided.

Comment: Just as a test, try implementing `viewDidAppear` and moving the call to `setUpSearchBar()` into `viewDidAppear`. Does it now behave correctly (ignoring any visual glitch)? You see the point: I'm trying to ascertain whether it's a _timing_ problem relative to layout.

Comment: Another idea: at some point before setting the offset, try saying `searchBar.sizeToFit()`.

Comment: @matt You are absolutely right! In terms of timing, it works when I put it in `viewDidAppear`. Now that we got that out of the way, what can we do next to avoid having it set up each time the view appears and only set it up once? Re: `searchBar.sizeToFit()` doesn't change anything in this particular instance.

Comment: I would suggest moving it into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and setting a flag so it only happens once. I'll give that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a timing problem relative to layout. Instead of calling `setUpSearchBar` in `viewDidLoad`, do it later, in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, when initial layout has actually taken place. This method can be called many times, so use a flag to prevent it from being called more than once:

```
var didSetUp = false
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if !didSetUp {
        didSetUp = true
        setUpSearchBar()
    }
}
```

Also: Your `animated` value is wrong:

```
newView.tableView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
```

You mean `false`. You don't want this movement to be visible. The table view should just appear with the search bar out of sight.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Follow up questions 
1) Would it be better to just use `tableView.contentOffset`? 
2) Where does `viewDidLayoutSubviews` fall in the ViewController lifecycle? Does it come before viewWillAppear?

Comment: (1) No because you want to explicitly _prevent_ the animation. (2) I don't think you should worry about its relationship to `viewWillAppear`. The important thing is what it _means_: it means that layout has taken place, and that's exactly what you want to wait for.

Comment: Great. Thanks so much, matt! I really appreciate all your help. This makes a lot more sense now.